# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'label_map_proto_file'

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

As soon as I switched to the current master version of the models (`c46caa568e692a6ce5e9f388cc277b2560ea9502`), I get the following error when trying to train my model:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/ubuntu/models/research/object_detection/trainer.py:210: create_global_step (from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.train.create_global_step
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/models/research/object_detection/train.py", line 163, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/home/ubuntu/models/research/object_detection/train.py", line 159, in main
    worker_job_name, is_chief, FLAGS.train_dir)
  File "/home/ubuntu/models/research/object_detection/trainer.py", line 217, in train
    train_config.prefetch_queue_capacity, data_augmentation_options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/models/research/object_detection/trainer.py", line 59, in create_input_queue
    tensor_dict = create_tensor_dict_fn()
  File "/home/ubuntu/models/research/object_detection/builders/input_reader_builder.py", line 72, in build
    label_map_proto_file=label_map_proto_file)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'label_map_proto_file'
```

If I switch back to the version `b4cf230287c534bac10c78b25c4412ff209cb417` everything is fine. Unfortunately I have no freaking idea where to start to fix this issue.

Comment: Which model you trying to train? Which versions of Python and Tensorflow did you use?

Comment: Im running it on an AWS E2 instance with Python 3.5.2. I am training with the `ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets` config.

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention the Tensorflow version. I've used `tensorflow-1.4.0rc0` as well as `tensorflow-1.4.0rc1`. I have the same issue with both.